# C Free Memory using free

Tags: c, memory

If you use `malloc()` to allocate memory for 4 integers, should it not return the memory adress of the first integer? And if so, shouldn't `free()` only free the first integer from the memory, while all the others are left behind?

Comment: Are you asking should C de designed explicitly to create memory leaks?

Comment: I just want to know how it works

Comment: No, you should `free()` the whole block, in fact if you pass a pointer that was not returned by one of *`malloc()` function, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Please write why you downvote :)

Comment: @ErikW But you're not asking how it works.

Comment: If you want to know exactly how it works, google `malloc.c` and look at the source of various implementations…

Answer (score 3):

> shouldn't free() only free the first integer from the memory, while all the others are left behind

No, it shouldn't, because otherwise calling `free` would result in a memory leak most of the time.

To answer the question I think you might have wanted to ask, `free` has to de-allocate the whole memory block pointed at by its argument. How it does that is implementation specific, but there has to be some book-keeping going on behind the scenes in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc()` keeps track of allocations made, including their size, and `free()` must be given exactly the address returned by `malloc()`, which causes that entire allocation to be freed at once.

Comment: On a related note, if you consider the alternative, `malloc()` would have to keep track of every individual byte since `malloc()` does not know the type of data you intend to put in there (e.g., `malloc(8)` could be eight bytes, two 32-bit integers, or one 64-bit integer).